# Robot framework textarea

Tags: robotframework

In robot framework how can I change line in textarea that text comes to new line . Now I have the following code:

```
: FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    10
    \    Input Text       id=edit-message     TestMessage\n
```

but now "TestMessage" writes on the previous one

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is typical to first fetch the value, then concatenate what you want added and then to overwrite the field with the new value.

```
: FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    10
\    ${textvalue}     Get Text       id=edit-message         
\    Input Text       id=edit-message     ${textvalue}\nTestMessage
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tWcdWLSy0zFTgVpiucOgVnScJJ0rX8SY/view?usp=sharing

Insert the $ {INDEX} index of the for loop into the input text locator to change the line and write to it.